# Issue with heap memory peaking

Tags: memory-leaks, tomcat7, heap-memory, java-7

I've been having trouble with my webapp. My heap memory peak up to nearly to max size for about 30 mins and the it crashes my system.

I have googled and tried nearly everything. I have been monitoring my heap memory using Java VisualVM, jconsole and Oracle Java Mission Control(I know it's outdated).

So what I have tried until know:

1. Monitored heap memory to see if there is a specific thread running at specific time and it peak the memory. (This is not the case as it doesn't specifically peak at specific times.)

2.Increased my heap memory size.

3. Followed instructions from:

http://karunsubramanian.com/websphere/top-4-java-heap-related-issues-and-how-to-fix-them/

So my questions are:

Is there any tool that can help me see if I have a memory leak and from where?
Has anyone experienced the same issue.
Any pointers on how to manage this kind of problems.

Btw I am quite new in this area so please be kind.

Tomcat 7 on Windows Server 2012
JAVA 7

If you need more information please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the jvm to create a heapdump when an outofmemory occurs.

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Then analyze the heap dump to find what classes are using the memory

Comment: I have already done this, What should I be looking at the size of the class or the retained memory?

Comment: retained memory as a "small" class can block the gc of several other classes. Find the dominator

Comment: Doesn't it point to any leak suspect (Proportionately higher amount of memory occupied by same object)?